# multivariable function in long-format dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Calculating a function of multiple variables for a dataframe in wide format is very familiar:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(t = 1:3, b = 11:13, c = 21:23) 
df <- df %>% mutate(d = b + c) # or base R: df$d <- df$b + df$c
```

What about when the dataframe is in long format? e.g.

```
df <- df %>% pivot_longer(-t, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")
```

In this long format, you could imagine the same operation working by first `group_by(t)`, and then calculating one value of d for each group, namely that group's variable=b value plus that group's variable=c value. Is this possible? One might think of something like `summarise(d = b + c)` but that expects wide format.
NB my real-world example has more than two cols b and c and I want to put them into a defined function, not just add them. My working solution is pivoting a huge dataframe from long to wide, calling my multivariable function to define a new column, then pivoting back to long.
**Edit:** to make the real world example explicit, I need to call a defined function that treats its arguments differently, unlike `sum`. For example

```
my.func <- function(b, c) { b^c }
```

How could the variable d be calculated by applying this function to the values of b and c associated with the same value of t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just do `sum` instead of `+`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(t) %>% 
    summarise(d =sum(value[variable %in% c('b', 'c')]))
```

---

If it is to apply the `my.func`, we need to extract the value that correspond to 'b', 'c'

```
df %>% 
    group_by(t)  %>%
    mutate(new = my.func(value[variable == 'b'], value[variable == 'c']))
```

Comment: Thanks, see the end of the post: summing is just an example. I need to work with different variables in the group by their name.

Comment: @ChrisW I updated the post.  Can you show your expected output

Comment: @ChrisW please check my edit.  As I said earlier, it is not clear whether you need `summarise` or `mutate`

Comment: That's great thanks: required behaviour achieved with bind_rows(df, df %>% group_by(t) %>% summarise(value = my.func(value[variable == 'b'], value[variable == 'c'])) %>% add_column(variable = "d"))